SSH works but SCP & RSYNC hang
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu MATE 21.04 to 22.04. I have two VMs, one running Centos 6.10 and the other CENTOS 7.
After the Ubuntu upgrade I had problems connecting from the VMs  to the host until I enable ecdsa keys. This got ssh working.
But I now have an issue with scp & rsync hanging. rsync -v prints nothing, it just hangs.
I'm running scp on the VM, transferring files to/from the host.
scp -vvv of host file to vm will report a long log that shows it authenticated and sent the scp command to the host and then nothing, it just hangs.
scp of a vm file to the host works.
I've attached the -vvv logs from both.
I've been on this for two days using Google and ChatGPT, but I'm not getting anywhere.
scp-client_to_host.log:
scp -v -r <user>@172.20.20.123:./test.txt .
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 172.20.20.123, user <user>, command scp -v -r -f ./test.txt
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/<user>/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/<user>/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 172.20.20.123
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.20.20.123 [172.20.20.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.20.20.123:22 as '<user>'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:9fjW5+2EQNQZmlrZ3F+hYDczp/tlUxIwqYA8OHnDPng
debug1: Host '172.20.20.123' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 172.20.20.123 ([172.20.20.123]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys:7: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys:7: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f ./test.txt

scp-host-to-client.log
